# Using scanf in VS Code with the Code Runner extension

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I tried a very simple code of C language using `scanf`, and it falls into the infinite loop(or it looks like).
the code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int input = 0;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    return 0;
}
```

I used the code runner extension. Here is the screenshot just in case.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlpPX.png)

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: The `scanf` will wait for some terminal input followed by ENTER

Comment: In other words - type something like: 42<ENTER> in the terminal window and the program will end.

Answer (score 6):

I just came across the same problem. In my case, just search "code-runner.run" in the setting and check the box as follow.

```
Code-runner: Run In Terminal
[] whether to run code in integrated terminal.
```

Image instruction:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Kindly frame the answer in a way its understandable to the other users. You can add images in a stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some code to make a better appearance for users, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int input = 0;
    printf("Please type in something:");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case you can know that the code is working and it gives you some feedback. Then you can type in the value which will be taken as input before the main function returns.

Comment: It still does not work... I tried and the printf function doesn't work either.

Comment: How about the "HelloWorld" test? The code is fine, the compiler or the IDE setup might need to be checked, to see whether there's something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I installed Mingw-64 and VS Code.  I installed Ming from Sourceforge.  When I went back and reviewed the directions for VSC, I noticed they recommended I download from MSYS2.  So I removed the original installation and re-installed from MSYS2. All my problems with scanf went away.  So my advice is to follow the installation instructions from the VSC website.  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw